# Use cookie for authentication in web api 2

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am implementing authentication in Web api with the Thinklecture library for WebApi authentication. It works fine with accesstoken in the url with the following code:

```
var config = new AuthenticationConfiguration();

// for testing
config.RequireSsl = false;

// security by user token
var handler = new SimpleSecurityTokenHandler("my access key", token =>
{
    if (ObfuscatingComparer.IsEqual(token, "accesskey123"))
    {
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim("customerid", "123")
        }, "Custom"));
    }

    return null;
});

config.AddAccessKey(handler, AuthenticationOptions.ForQueryString("userToken"));
```

Here, AuthenticationConfiguration is a part of the Thinklecture library.

What I do not get to work is when trying to use cookies for authentication with the following code. I have verified in fiddler that the cookie is sent correctly.

```
var handler2 = new SimpleSecurityTokenHandler("my access key", token =>
{
    if (ObfuscatingComparer.IsEqual(token, "accesskey123"))
    {
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim("customerid", "123")
        }, "Custom"));
    }

    return null;
});

config.AddAccessKey(handler2, AuthenticationOptions.ForCookie("company.userToken"));
```

Am I using this library wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The cookie option is not implemented.